# Conversion to python of C code

Tags: python, c, django

For use in a web backend (django) project, I am given the following C code snippet:

```
/* architecture is x86_64, strings are ASCII */
/* example output:
 * 7KL753WG => 680403628
 * 043NM2B6 => 517135930
 * 7B6ISP72 => 058511020
 */

char buf[33];
char*  unlock(char *s) {
  char  token[9];
  char  scrambled[9];
  long long *ltoken;

  strncpy(token,s,9);

  ltoken=(long long *)token;

  *ltoken *= 610;
  *ltoken ^= 0x5A5A5A5A ;

  buf[32]='\0';

  int i = snprintf(buf,32,"%lld",*ltoken);
  return buf+i-9;
}
```

In words: take an 8 char ascii string, use its bit pattern as a long, apply a couple of computations, take the last 9 digits of the result.

For obvious reasons, I'd hate to shell out to call the binary, and would like to convert it to python 2.7. On the other hand, I have tried the obvious (struct.pack, struct.unpack) and the exotic (ctypes) with no joy. I assume ctypes is the way to go, but I have never used it so my attempts are basically poking at it with a stick.
**EDIT**:
This is what I tried.
pack/unpack (just wrong):

```
from sys import stderr
import struct

expected= {
    '7KL753WG' : "680403628",
    '043NM2B6': "517135930",
    '7B6ISP72' : "058511020",
    }

def trans(ary):
    ret=[]
    for v in ary: ret.append((v*610)^0x5A5A5A5A)
    return ret

def func(token):
    Q=struct.unpack('Q',token)
    I=struct.unpack('II',token)
    S=struct.unpack('hhhh',token)

    print("(Q/L) %s => %s"%(token,','.join(map(str,trans(Q)))))
    print("(I)   %s => %s"%(token,','.join(map(str,trans(I)))))
    print("(S)   %s => %s"%(token,','.join(map(str,trans(S)))))
    print("==== expected last 9 digits as %s ====="%(expected.get(token,"NOT FOUND"),))


for s in ('7KL753WG','043NM2B6', '7B6ISP72'):  func(s)
```

ctypes: promising, but I could not find a way to perform math among ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *

aa="043NM2B6"
pb=create_string_buffer(aa)
#pl.contents becomes c_long(3909742734116860976) (which is right)
pl=cast(pb,POINTER(c_longlong))
# this is an error
result=(pl.contents * c_longlong(610)) ^ c_longlong(0x5A5A5A5A)
```

**EDIT** Since there are requests for clarification:

I want to write a python function that gives me the same results as the above C code when invoked on the same input. Because the C code itself depends on the internal data representation of strings and long integers ( as per ltoken=(long long *)token) I have so far been unable to find a way to do it, and my several attempts have been fruitless.

I do not want to call system() or moral equivalents from within my python code, as it makes the entire thing more brittle and adds dependencies.

Hence the question.

(And yes, I know that the algorithm itself is not pretty - luckily not something I wrote)

TIA

**EDIT:** (downvoters would be kind/polite to leave a reason)

Comment: So what's stopping you from writing this in Python? And why do you want to?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - (i) My attempts at conversion did not work (they give different results) (ii) I do not want to use system (or equivalents) and have additional files/dependencies etc. 
It's all explained in the post.

Comment: Show your attempts at rewriting in python.  People can the look at your attempt and perhaps determine what is wrong.

Comment: Also, it looks like the original code breaks the rules of strict aliasing.

Comment: I'm sure you were downvoted because this was read as a "please help me convert this to Python" without showing what you actually did try and boil it down to more specific technical questions. SO abhors questions that start to smell like "do this conversion for me". (I was not one of the DV crew, however.)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons the original code compiles cleanly and that's about all it has got going for it. It's atrocious hack that is architecture and (possibly) compiler dependent. But there's nothing I can do to change it. I am adding examples of what I tried to do as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the python 2.7 `int` type is 64-bit, then

```
import sys
from struct import pack, unpack

def unlock(s):
    val = unpack('<q', ('%s\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' % s)[0:8])[0]
    val = val * 610
    val = val ^ 0x5a5a5a5a
    val = val & 18446744073709551615
    if val > 9223372036854775807:
        val = val - 18446744073709551616
    return ('%d' % val)[-9:]
```

but oh boy, is that a horrible hack..

If anyone asks, I didn't write the above code, okay?

---

In the above code, `(%s\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' % s)[0:8]` takes at most 8 first characters from `s`, and pads it to exactly 8 characters with zeros. `unpack('<q', ...)` converts that to an 8-byte (64-bit signed) integer. The result is a tuple with just a single element, so the final '[0]' simply grabs the 64-bit result.

The rest of the code is hard to understand, unless you know that Python supports both normal integers (of at least 32 bits), and ["long integers"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) with unlimited precision (size).

Essentially, the multiplication by 610 may turn `val` into an unlimited precision "long integer". To limit to 64 bit precision, we do a binary AND with 2<sup>64</sup>-1.

The original code relies on 64-bit *signed* integers, however, with `LLONG_MAX == 9223372036854775807`. This means that if our value is greater than 9223372036854775807, we need to subtract 2<sup>64</sup> from it. Originally, I did that in two parts (by 2<sup>63</sup> = 9223372036854775808), in the hopes that it would keep the value as a normal (limited precision) integer. It turns out it does not matter, and a single subtraction will work just as well.

Comment: Gee, that works, even if I do not understand it! Care to explain? (I swear I won't tell.) And, is the val = val - 9223372036854775808 really repeated twice?

Comment: @AlienLifeForm, I believe the duplicated subtraction line is correct but can be combined into the single line: `val -= 2 << 63`  If I understand the code correctly, this is where a twos complement correction happens for negative values.